# ROS Install - No space left on device, Fresh 16GB SD Card

Tags: ros, installation, raspberrypi, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm installing ROS on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, and I'm generally following the [debian installation procedure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian). When I got to step 1.3.2 and tried to run `rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"` everything installs fine except for the visualization_common, gazebo and vcstools packages. I get hit with the following error:

> `[visualization_common] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/stacks/visualization_common/visualization_common-1.8.4/visualization_common-1.8.4.tar.bz2 (version visualization_common-1.8.4) to /home/pi/ros/visualization_common ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: [Errno 28] No space left on device[/vcstools]`

After swapping a 4GB SD card for a 16GB SD card, here's the current state of my system (and I'm still getting these "No space left on device" errors!).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           15G  2.2G   12G  16% /
/dev/root        15G  2.2G   12G  16% /
tmpfs            19M  212K   19M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            37M     0   37M   0% /tmp
tmpfs            10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs            37M     0   37M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M   34M   23M  61% /boot
pi@raspberrypi:~$ df -i
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs         974848 106097 868751   11% /
dev/root      974848 106097 868751   11% /
tmpfs           23510    228  23282    1% /run
tmpfs           23510      2  23508    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           23510      3  23507    1% /tmp
tmpfs           23510    314  23196    2% /dev
tmpfs           23510      1  23509    1% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1      0      0      0     - /boot
```

So, any ideas why ROS might think I have no space left?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51238/ros-install---no-space-left-on-device,-fresh-16gb-sd-card/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2012-12-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out, a simple Raspberry Pi firmware update fixed everything: https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/

Always remember to update your firmware, kids!

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2012-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2